# how the Android SDK talks to the internal GPS SDK

Tags: java, android, gps

I'm happily developing GPS aware apps using `LocationManager` and `NmeaListener`, so I am not asking about how to use the Android SDK, but how the Android SDK talks to the internal GPS SDK

I'm trying to understand how Android interacts with the GPS SDK to deliver, for example, the speed and direction values in the GPRMC sentence. Do they come directly from the chip SDK or are they calculatedd by Android?
I'm looking at Android source in `LocationManager.java`, but I can't find where it interacts with the GPS SDK.
Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

I expect the GPS is a separate sub system which reports data to the system over a serial NMEA connection. If so then the GPS module will calculate Speed (SOG) and Course (COG) using internal methods. For low cost GPS modules they typically have a filtered position difference method. Higher end GPS receivers use carrier phase measurements to get instant results.

I'm guessing that you are noticing a lag in the COG and SOG values and hoping that knowing more about how they are derived will help you correct the lag...

Comment: Yes, you're right, the GPS is a separate sub-system. My Samsung SGS 11 uses the SiRF chip, which, as I read in their documentation, comes with an SDK, but the details are not freely available. I suspect you need to be a deep pocketed manufacturer to get those. I was hoping to get a peek by locating the Android code that uses the SDK to resolve some of these questions.

Comment: And yes, I've built a small app that does Dead Reckoning from the COG and SOG values and compares the results with the Position data. Surprisingly good over 1/2 hr and 30 km, but with some inexplicable excursions.

Comment: considering that the COG and SOG are derived from position solutions, it will make since that they match up. Where you may see significant differences is when dynamics are involved. Like in a turn. Also position noise will dominate the COG and SOG values at low speeds. low cost receiver often switch to a static filter when they detect that they are not moving. Adding to the lag you see when they agian start moving, also this static filter might be fooled at low speeds.